# Drain plumbing under sink to washer to main drain

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing the drain pipe from the kitchen sink to the washer drain to the main drain under the house. Can I use fernco couplers?

Comment: that is what they are made for

Answer (score 1):

Fernco coupling are allowed but keep them accessible, no connections under the house.